# Disinfecting woodwind instruments

Tags: woodwinds, instrument-cleaning

I've bought an interesting instrument recently, a [zurna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurna), which I was really excited about. The problem is the same day I first used it (without cleaning it before, yes I know, stupid) I got quite an unpleasant case of gastroenteritis. I can not say for certain that zurna is to blame, nevertheless I want to thoroughly disinfect the instrument before I play it again. There was already a question about effect of rubbing alcohol on reeds. Although I am interested if there are any commonly used techniques of cleaning and disinfecting woodwind instruments besides it, that would least damage them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubbing alcohol will not damage the wood of reeds or the body of the instrument.  But there might be problems with the surface finish (if any) of the instrument and/or any glue used on the reed.  I don't know of any other disinfectant that wouldn't cause more problems than rubbing (isopropyl) alcohol, though.  Try it out on a small area first.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer, but I'll add as a comment: I didn't see the answer at the time so I just thoroughly washed the mouthpiece with soap and water and then washed it when 95% alcohol. Played it without any problems. Don't know if this is an appropriate process but seems to work in my case.